# How to create an Update statement from a subquery in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to update all records that match my criteria. But the `Sql` below is giving this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

```
-- Set MasterAccountId = NULL where there is no Receivable with equivalent BillingAccountId and TaskAccountId 
UPDATE R
SET R.MasterAccountId = NULL  
FROM Receivable R
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM MasterAccount M 
                WHERE (ISNULL(M.BillingAccountId, 0) > 0 AND M.BillingAccountId = R.BillingAccountId) OR 
                      (ISNULL(M.TaskAccountId, 0) > 0 AND M.TaskAccountId = R.TaskAccountId))
```

Basically, I need to update **all records** that return in that `subquery`.

Does any one know how to fix it?

Comment: Which table do you want to update: `MasterAccount` or `Receivable`?

Comment: Also, I don't think that SQL will produce the quoted error. Did you copy the right code?

Comment: I want to update: Receivable.MasterAccountId, I want to set NULL in that field for all the records in receivable that have the matching BillingAccountId or TaskAccountId in the MasterAccount table. @Blorgbeard

Comment: Yes, I ran the same Sql in Sql Server the complete error is: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SetReceivableMasterAccount, Line 47
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give a try on this. This is base from the repond of https://stackoverflow.com/users/40655/robin-day on this link [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server).

```
UPDATE 
    R
SET
    R.MasterAccountId = NULL 
FROM
    Receivable R
INNER JOIN
    MasterAccount M
ON
    (ISNULL(M.BillingAccountId, 0) > 0 AND M.BillingAccountId = R.BillingAccountId) OR 
    (ISNULL(M.TaskAccountId, 0) > 0 AND M.TaskAccountId = R.TaskAccountId))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are getting the said error in posted query May be somewhere else. Again in your `EXISTS` subquery, instead of saying `select * ...` it's always better to say `WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM MasterAccount M`

Also try using the `JOIN` version of this query instead like

```
UPDATE R
SET R.MasterAccountId = NULL  
FROM Receivable R
JOIN MasterAccount M ON M.BillingAccountId = R.BillingAccountId 
OR M.TaskAccountId = R.TaskAccountId
WHERE ISNULL(M.BillingAccountId, 0) > 0 
OR ISNULL(M.TaskAccountId, 0) > 0;
```

Comment: I am so sorry guys, but I found the problem. I have another trigger, this error comes from the trigger... :(